# Proyecto Pomodoro no funciona JS, error null

Tags: javascript, html5, null

**Estoy haciendo un proyecto Pomodoro en JS. Siguiendo un tutorial pero llega un punto que no funciona. Si ejecutan el codigo les tira erro de valor nulo. Ya mire el video como 4 veces y no encuentro el error :( PD: Me pide que agregue más descripción y ya nose que más agregar, espero que con un loren Ipsum sea suficiente.
What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.**

[De aquí saque la idea del proyecto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfaiDc585Eo&t=1778s)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Codigo JS**

```js
//Aqui se almacenan, las tareas que puedo ir ejecutando con la técnica POMODORO
const tasks = [];
let time = 0;
let timer = null;
let timerBreak = null;
let current = null;

const bAdd = document.querySelector("#bAdd");
const itTask = document.querySelector("#itTask");
const form = document.querySelector("#form");
const taskName = document.querySelector("#time #taskname");

// EVENTOS: Se ejecuta una funcion cuando se prenda o dispare el metodo de submit
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (itTask.value !== "") {
    createTask(itTask.value);
    itTask.value = "";
    renderTasks();
  }
});

// Funcion para crear una tarea
function createTask(value) {
  const newTask = {
    id: (Math.random() * 100).toString(36).slice(3),
    title: value,
    completed: false,
  };

  tasks.unshift(newTask);
}
/*FUNCION: Esta funcion, me permite  tomar cada uno de los elementos de las tareas y generar un HTML,
que al final voy a inyectar en un contenedor*/
function renderTasks() {
  const html = tasks.map((task) => {
    return `
        <div class="task">
            <div class="completed">${
              task.completed
                ? `<span class="done">Done</span>`
                : `<button class="start-button" data-id="${task.id}">Start</button>`
            }</div>
            <div class="title">${task.title}</div>
        </div>

       `;
  });

  const taskContainer = document.querySelector("#tasks");
  taskContainer.innerHTML = html.join("");

  /*(Botones) 
    El objeto DOCUMENT, sirve para modificar de manera dinamica, es decir en tiempo de 
    ejecucion todos los elementos de nuestra pagina. Este objeto tiene funciones: Las cuales
    es recomendable buscarlas en "https://developer.mozilla.org/es/"*/
  const StartButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".task .start-button");
  StartButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (!timer) {
        const id = button.getAttribute("data-id");
        startButtonHandler(id);
        button.textContent = "In progress...";
      }
    });
  });
}

/* Funcion de Boton definida */

function startButtonHandler(id) {
  time = 25 * 60;
  current = id;
  const taskIndex = tasks.findIndex((task) => task.id == id);
  taskName.textContent = tasks[taskIndex].title;
  /*Esto controla el tiempo*/
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    timerHandler(id);
  }, 1000);
}

function timerHandler(id) {
  time--;
  renderTime();
  if (time == 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    current = null;
    taskName.textContent = "";
    renderTime();
  }
}
/*Esta Funcion renderiza el tiempo. Lo hace visible, darle formato a un numero */
function renderTime() {
  const timeDiv = document.querySelector("#time #value");
  const minutes = parseInt(time / 60);
  const seconds = parseInt(time % 60);
  /*Esto le da el formato */
  timeDiv.textContent = `${minutes < 10 ? "0" : ""}${minutes}:${
    seconds < 10 ? "0" : ""
  }${seconds}`;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pomodoro</title>
    <!--La etiqueta HTML link (que crea lo que se conoce como "hiperenlace") es una etiqueta que 
    normalmente enlaza externamente (a otra página o documento en una web diferente) o internamente 
    (a otros recursos en tu web). En este caso, enlaza al archivo main_Pomodoro.css-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main_Pomodoro.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <!--Estructura basica para mostrar el contador-->
    <div id="app">  
            <div id="time">
                <div id="value"></div>
                <div id="taskName"></div>
            </div>
        
<!--Segunda capa de la interfas-->
        <div class="tasks-container">
            <div class="form">
                <form action="" id="form">
                    <input type="text" id="itTask">
                    <input type="submit" id="bAdd" value="Agregar Tarea"/>
            </form>
            <!--Aqui se colocaran todas las tareas que valla creando-->
                <div id="tasks">

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--El atributo 'src' en una etiqueta es la ruta hacia un archivo externo o recurso que quieres 
    enlazar a tu documento HTML. Esto apuntaría a un archivo llamado 'script.js' que está en el 
    mismo directorio del archivo--> 
    <script src="main_Pomodoro.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola maestro, podrías agregar el código del error?.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')
    at startButtonHandler (main_Pomodoro.js:75:24)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main_Pomodoro.js:62:9)
startButtonHandler @ main_Pomodoro.js:75
(anónimo) @ main_Pomodoro.js:62

Comment: ese error te lo arroja cuando le das al botón **start**?

Comment: puede que el error se produzca por esta linea **const taskName = document.querySelector("#time #taskname");**, prueba con **const taskName = document.querySelector("#taskname");** y otra distinta para **"#time"**.

Comment: Exacto, cuando le doy al boton start me tira esos 2 errores. OK ya pruebo eso gracias

Comment: Esa es la linea 11 no?

Comment: exacto, es la que creo que falla, ya que le estás pidiendo el contenido a dos elementos.

Comment: OK, compa lo reviso y mañana te aviso gracias

Comment: Hola Bro. Hice lo que me dijiste pero tuve que cambiarle el nombre a la varaible time por time1.  const taskName = document.querySelector("#taskname");
const time1 = document.querySelector("#time");

Comment: Pero sigue sin funcionar, le cambie el nombre a la variable porque ya habia otra variable con ese mismo nombre

Comment: Si mal no entendí, tu me dijiste que declare 2 varaibles por separado, una para **time** y otra para **taskname**

Comment: Este es el error que me tira cuando le doy al boton Start [enlace](https://ibb.co/B2HTKcb)

Comment: Maestro, el error *const taskName = document.querySelector( "#time"**,** "#taskname" );*, faltaba la coma, al igual que en: *** const timeDiv = document.querySelector("#time, #value");***,... ahora se ejecuta la tarea.